# Fire event to get javascript value in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Still new to asp.net but I'm using a master site and I have a dropdown feature in the navigation bar to let the user log out.

I'm trying to set the value of an ASPx.HiddenField using javascript. But without a service side button event I'm not sure where(master page.vb or login page.vb) or how to use the value in the Hidden Field. I'll try to add all the reliant code.

JavaScript:

```
    function redirect(string) {
        if (string == 'login.aspx') { 
            LogOutSession.Set('logged', true); //set value of HiddenField
        }
        window.open(string, '_self'); //redirect to the selected page

    }
```

Html:

```
  <select onchange = "redirect(value)">
 <option>
 </option>
 <option value="default.aspx"> Home</option>
 <option value="contactForm.aspx"> Contact Us</option>
 <option value="login.aspx">Log out</option>
 </select>
```

ASPx.HiddenField code:

```
 <dx:ASPxHiddenField ID="LogOutSession" ClientInstanceName="LogOutSession" runat="server" >
             </dx:ASPxHiddenField>
```

Code I'm trying to use when they get back to the login page

VB:

```
   'remove session
    Session("LoggedIn") = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the value to hidden field by it's client ID, please check ClientID of the hidden field in view source, it's probably "ctl00_LogOutSession" as per your code snippet, other wise replace it with what you found in view source.

try this

```
function redirect(string) {
    if (string == 'login.aspx') { 
        document.getElementById('ctl00_LogOutSession').value="true"; //set value of HiddenField
    }
    window.open(string, '_self'); //redirect to the selected page

}
```

also make session to null instead of set it to false

Session.Abandon() is the best practice.

Comment: Thank you for the foot note on .Abandon() - I'll bear that in mind for the future of my project.

I can set it in the console using your method above, as long as use "ctl00_LogOutSession_I". It's allowing me to set or get the value when it's in my JS. 

If I can set it using the LogOutSession.Get('valueName', value); option, would you know of the best event trigger in the code behind to get that information?

Comment: as per my understanding, whenever user selects Login.aspx page u want to remove session in master page

if so, you can do it in couple of ways with out hidden varialbe.

one is,
modify javascript function like below

    if (string == 'login.aspx')
        window.open(string+'?logout=1', '_self'); 
    else
       window.open(string, '_self');
 and check query string in master page page load event with in not post back conditon, its something like below in C#

if (!IsPostBack)
{if (Request.QueryString["logout"] != null && Request.QueryString["logout"].ToString() == "1")
Session.Abandon();
}
}

Comment: Very simple way to do it and works perfectly! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting hidden field value like this:

```
document.getElementById("hiddenFieldId").value="value goes here";
```

Comment: I tried this before and I wasn't able to set the value. I can set the value okay on the JS side using the Get() function, it's using it server side(in the vb code) I seem to be having issues with.

Comment: So hidden field's value is set on the client side but you don't get it in code behind?

Comment: I can't get it in the code behind because there is no event that requires the code to go behind, such as an ASPxButton click, was trying page load and unload, and that doesn't work.

Comment: May be you can try with page methods or server side control (dropdown list)?